# MailJet & PostFix E-mails Delayed (around 10-60 minutes)

Tags: email, ubuntu, postfix-mta, mailjet

My text e-mails sent by PostFix & MailJet are quite delayed. If I get an e-mail, it will be delayed too, same with sending.

Here is my configuration file:

```html
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no
# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h
readme_directory = no
# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=no
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = offermoon.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = offermoon.com
relayhost = in-v3.mailjet.com:2525
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
default_transport= smtp
```

Comment: Provide an example of logs of any delayed message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mailjet is responsible for relaying your emails but as far as receiving is concerned, Mailjet should not be involved. Since the problem affects both sending and receiving, the issue could be related to the DNS or to some local limits. The best way to go is to take few message headers from delayed messages and analyze them. You can use some of the online tools which will show you where the delay is and you will take it from there. You can try MXtoolbox for example:
http://mxtoolbox.com/EmailHeaders.aspx